# Conectando Go com MongoDB utilizando Docker

Tags: mongodb, golang, docker

Estou criando um microserviço em Go, utilizando MongoDB como banco de dados e utilizando a biblioteca `mgo`.

Utilizando o MongoDB em um container do docker localmente e rodando a aplicação na minha maquina, tudo funciona normalmente, porém quando fui tentar executar utilizando um arquivo do docker compose eu não consegui realizar a conexão entre o Go e o MongoDB

O Dockerfile utilizado para gerar a imagem:

```
FROM golang:1.9.2 as builder
WORKDIR /app
RUN go get -u gopkg.in/mgo.v2
RUN go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin
COPY .  .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o microservice .

FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /app/microservice .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./microservice"]
```

O código do docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api-user:
    image: "api-user"
    links:
     - "mongodb"
    environment:
     - MONGO_URL="mongodb"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: "mongo"
```

Esse é o código que realiza a conexão no Go:

```
session, err := mgo.Dial(os.Getenv("MONGO_URL"))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

O erro lançado pelo Go:

```
panic: no reachable servers
```

Executando o ping no container do microserviço, o MongoDB retorna confirmando que existe conexão entre os containers.

Já tentei utilizar a string de conexão da [documentação do MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/connection-string/) e mesmo assim não tive sucesso

Comment: Acredito que o seu problema seja com o docker e não com o go em si. Estou em dúvida naquelas aspas no valor da chave do environment. Aquele `links` no docker compose me parece desnecessário também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como eu também estou "brincando" com docker recentemente, resolvi fazer alguns testes.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    mgo "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

func main() {
    url := os.Getenv("MONGO_URL")

    fmt.Printf("[%v]\n", url)
    session, err := mgo.Dial(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("ping", session.Ping())
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM scratch
COPY myapp /
CMD ["/myapp"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    image: custom-myapp
    environment: 
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: "mongo"
```

Só executar:

> docker-compose up --build --force-recreate

Output:

```
Building myapp
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
 --->
Step 2/3 : COPY docker /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9b265efb7057
Step 3/3 : CMD /docker
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8e8ac4e3cb71
Successfully built 8e8ac4e3cb71
Successfully tagged custom-myapp:latest
Recreating docker_mongodb_1 ...
Recreating docker_mongodb_1 ... done
Recreating docker_myapp_1 ...
Recreating docker_myapp_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_mongodb_1, docker_myapp_1
mongodb_1  | 2017-12-14T01:31:43.888+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=c4db7d1bfabc
mongodb_1  | 2017-12-14T01:31:43.888+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.0
mongodb_1  | 2017-12-14T01:31:43.888+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a57d8e71e6998a2d0afde7edc11bd23e5661c915
myapp_1    | [mongodb]
mongodb_1  | 2017-12-14T01:31:43.888+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
myapp_1    | ping <nil>
mongodb_1  | 2017-12-14T01:31:43.888+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongodb_1  | 2017-12-14T01:31:43.888+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
...
mongodb_1  | 2017-12-14T01:31:44.304+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
mongodb_1  | 2017-12-14T01:31:45.476+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.3:58192 #1 (1 connection now open)
mongodb_1  | 2017-12-14T01:31:45.542+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 172.20.0.3:58192 (0 connections now open)
docker_myapp_1 exited with code 0
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping docker_mongodb_1 ... done
```

Como pode ver ali, assim que o servidor ficou disponível a conexão foi feita.

O problema realmente não é o go em si, mas sim aquelas aspas extras no `MONGO_URL` do docker-compose.yaml.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, muito obrigado, não sabia que nas variáveis de ambiente não podia ter aspas quando é referencia a outro serviço, achei que como ele colocaria no hosts, apenas o nome seria suficiente.

Comment: Pra ser sincero, eu também não sabia! Por isso resolvi testar aqui e aprender junto com você. Não precisa de aspas, inclusive quando tem espaços na variável de ambiente. :D